# I cannot ping from server to new vlan interface

Tags: cisco, switch, router, vlan

I created new dhcp pool in server 2012 called **vlan 41**,routed with default gateway in router, added **interface vlan 41** on core switch 3650.

`interface Vlan41`

`ip address 10.10.41.250 255.255.255.0`

`ip helper-address 10.10.10.1`

i can't ping to this interface from server

**Routed 10.10.41.0 255.255.255.0**

**Other dhcp pools are working fine**

Comment: how can i delete previous question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can not comment to the original question. So i write it here:
try this:

```
Conf t
interface Vlan41
sh
no sh
end
wr
```

and now try to ping from th server.

Comment: can you ping the server from the core SW?

Comment: i can ping from the core sw to server

Comment: try to trace route the core Sw managment IP and also traxe route the IP:10.10.41.250.

Comment: tracert management IP working fine, tracert 10.10.41.250 take away to public addreses

Comment: than this is a problem on core SW side. do you have any static routes configured? please share with us.

Comment: its 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(router address)

Comment: not enough info.. :( what is the default gateway on the core?

Comment: one more question: On the core SW is the VLAN41 added? I mean this command:`conf t --> VLAN 42 --> name xxxx --> end`

Comment: yes, i named the vlan on core SW

Comment: Thanks Mr. István Fonyó, i have two routers, the Gateway address for the server is the second router and there is no vlan interface for **vlan 41**.  ** tracert 10.10.41.250 ** helps me to solve this one.